# Why try catch block performance differ from general block in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tested try catch block and try catch block less method in angularjs. But why performance differ from one another. Please describe me.

```
var format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'

$scope.time1 = new Date();

$scope.time2 = new Date();

$scope.dif = 0;

$scope.TestMethod = function () {
    var a = 0;

    $scope.time1 = new Date();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {

        a +=i;

    }

    $scope.time2 = new Date();
    calculateDif();
}

$scope.TryCatchMethod = function () {
    try {
        var a = 0;

        $scope.time1 = new Date();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {

            a +=i;
        }
        $scope.time2 = new Date();
        calculateDif();
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }       
}
function calculateDif(){
    $scope.dif = $scope.time2-$scope.time1;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rb1IGuq7x1LIkj1G0R4G?p=preview

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://jsperf.com/try-catch-performance-overhead

Comment: Performance obviously differs because you're doing two different things? Please explain why you had not expected that, so we can clear up your misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks, But I need to know more detail. When I have run such code from my computer then I have get try catch block is 5 times faster than no try catch block. But When I have set my code into Plunker I have got no try catch block is faster than try catch block.